# How to import PCs into Fantasy Grounds?

Tags: character-creation, character-sheets, fantasy-grounds

Hey so me and my group just migrated to Fantasy Grounds and we tested it using the premade characters of LMoP, but now that we are somewhat confident into using it we would like to ditch the premade chars and import our own. The problem is that we don't really know how to create the xml that FG needs to import so I wonder if there is a tool (maybe to convert it from friendlier formats like json or yaml) or maybe if you guys are aware of a guideline on how to create it. I just want to avoid to manually edit every single field on the sheet of FG or replicate the creation process using the core pack because some stuff would be custom

Thanks for your help!

Angelo

Answer (score 5):

Writing XML by hand is *extremely* complicated. Just enter them by hand into Fantasy Grounds' sheets — they exist because it's simpler that way!

Comment: well, the whole purpose of the post was exactly to NOT write xml by hand but like I said I was already entering them manually, I just wanted to probe for the existence of a wrapper in a friendlier meta language